# Why can't i get data value from json - flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Am trying to get values from my json file `categories.json` using flutter but am always getting error or its not showing and I don't really know what is wrong
This is my **main.dart**

```
 Future<List<Category>> loadData() async {
    String jString = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/categories.json");
    List<dynamic> jRes = jsonDecode(jString);
    List<Category> datas = jRes.map((e) => Category.fromJson(e)).toList();
    return datas;
  }


Container(
  child: FutureBuilder<List<Category>>(
      future: loadData(),
      builder: (context, data) {
        if (data.connectionState != ConnectionState.waiting &&
            data.hasData) {
          var userList = data.data;
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: userList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var userData = userList[index];
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("Category: ${userData.catName}"),
                  ],
                );
              });
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      })),
```

and my **model.dart**

```
class Category {
  String catId;
  String catName;
  SubCategory subcat;

  Category({this.catId, this.catName, this.subcat});
  factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Category(
      catId: json['cat_id'],
      catName: json['category'],
      subcat: SubCategory.fromJson(json['cat_subcategory']),
    );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "cat_id": catId,
      "category": catName,
    };
  }
}

class SubCategory {
  String subName, subImage;

  SubCategory({this.subName, this.subImage});
  factory SubCategory.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SubCategory(subName: json['sub_name'], subImage: json['sub_image']);
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "sub_name": subName,
      "sub_image": subImage,
    };
  }
}
```

and lastly my **categories.json** file

```
[{
        "category": "Design & Creativity",
        "cat_id": "1",
        "cat_subcategory": [
            {
                "sub_name": "Ads",
                "sub_image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589838017489-9198a27bd040?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8YWR2ZXJ0aXNlbWVudHxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
            }
           
          
        ]
    }]

//There are more of them
```

The problem am facing when I run it is that it only shows me the `CircularProgressIndicator()` in my **main.dart** and when I remove the **if statement**, it says `Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.` Please how do I go about solving this problem and if you need more explanation then tell me

PS: When I check the `loadData()` value it says `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

EDIT: Thank you all for the answers but what i did was to generate a model using this website [model generator](https://app.quicktype.io)

and i was able to get the value

Comment: If you remove `if` statement your data can be not initialized. Are you tried to check data for valid state? `loadData` method returned valid result?

Comment: @fartem how do i check if it's valid. Sorry am new to flutter

Comment: You can debug your app or print your variables in logs.

Comment: @fartem it said `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

Comment: Try parse your file as object, not list. Use `Map<String, dynamic>` instead of `List<dynamic>`. Can you post your JSON file?

Comment: @fartem its in the description just multiple of that

Comment: Try to view all values in JSON in debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, when I want to load data from json file, I do this:

```
  Future<List<Category>> loadData() async {
    List<Category> datas = [];
    return rootBundle.loadString("assets/categories.json").then((value) {
      List<dynamic> jRes = jsonDecode(value);
      jRes.forEach((element) {
        datas.add(Category.fromJson(element));
      });
      return datas;
    });
  }
```

Also, in *SubCategory* class

```dart
factory SubCategory.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SubCategory(subName: json['sub_name'], subImage: json['sub_image']);
  }
```

Your *fromJson()* require *Map<String, dynamic>*.

But if you look at your file

```
"cat_subcategory": [
            {
                "sub_name": "Ads",
                "sub_image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589838017489-9198a27bd040?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8YWR2ZXJ0aXNlbWVudHxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
            }
           
          
        ]
```

You can see that *cat_subcategory* is a List

So you are giving a List to your *SubCategory.fromJson()* instead of a Map.
If you want to give a Map, you can simply give the first index of your list

*Your Category.fromJson() become*

```
factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Category(
      catId: json['cat_id'],
      catName: json['category'],
      subcat: SubCategory.fromJson(json['cat_subcategory'][0]),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your model.dart class

```
class Category {
String category;
String catId;
List<CatSubcategory> catSubcategory;

Category({this.category, this.catId, this.catSubcategory});

Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
category = json['category'];
catId = json['cat_id'];
if (json['cat_subcategory'] != null) {
  catSubcategory = new List<CatSubcategory>();
  json['cat_subcategory'].forEach((v) {
    catSubcategory.add(new CatSubcategory.fromJson(v));
  });
}}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
data['category'] = this.category;
data['cat_id'] = this.catId;
if (this.catSubcategory != null) {
  data['cat_subcategory'] =
      this.catSubcategory.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
}
return data;
}}

class CatSubcategory {
String subName;
String subImage;

CatSubcategory({this.subName, this.subImage});

CatSubcategory.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
subName = json['sub_name'];
subImage = json['sub_image'];
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
data['sub_name'] = this.subName;
data['sub_image'] = this.subImage;
return data;
}}
```

And Replace

```
List<Category> datas = jRes.map((e) => Category.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

with

```
List<Category> datas = List<Category>.from(jRes.map((category)=> Category.fromJson(category)));
```